# Combine integers in list into one integer

Tags: python, arrays, string, integer, array-combine

this is what I wish for...

**INPUT** `[1,2,3,4,5]`

**OUTPUT** `12345`

I've tried this but it didn't work...

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print([int(n1) for n1 in str(l1).split() if n1.isdigit()])
```

Comment: You're going much too complicated. Just do `"".join(l1)`

Comment: @Kemp That won't work since `l1` does not contain strings

Comment: Oops, you're right. It would have to be more like `"".join([str(x) for x in l1])`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result to be an integer, the following should do the trick:

```
int(''.join([str(i) for i in l1]))
```

---

If you still want it as a string then simply do

```
''.join([str(i) for i in l1])
```